# getting scikit-learn version warning using yml environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I want to deploy a machine learning model and have the environment yml file and the model pickle file. When I include `scikit-learn=0.23.2` to the dependencies, conda automatically uninstall this scikit-learn version and install `scikit-learn-0.24.2` . Therefore, I get the following warning when I load the pickle file.

UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use
at your own risk.

Here is the environment:

```
name: environment
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - blas=1.0
  - ca-certificates=2021.5.25
  - certifi=2021.5.30
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0
  - intel-openmp=2021.2.0
  - joblib=0.17.0
  - mkl=2020.2
  - mkl-service=2.3.0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.0
  - mkl_random=1.1.1
  - numpy=1.19.2
  - numpy-base=1.19.2
  - openssl=1.1.1k
  - pandas=1.2.4
  - patsy=0.5.1
  - pickleshare=0.7.5
  - pip=21.1.1
  - pyodbc=4.0.30
  - python=3.7.4
  - python-dateutil
  - pytz=2021.1
  - scipy=1.6.2
  - setuptools=52.0.0
  - six=1.15.0
  - sqlite=3.35.4
  - statsmodels=0.12.0
  - threadpoolctl=2.1.0
  - vc=14.2
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016
  - wheel=0.36.2
  - wincertstore=0.2
  - scikit-learn=0.23.2
  - pip:
    - imblearn==0.0
prefix: C:\Users
```

And the result of `conda env create -f environment.yml` is:

```
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, imbalanced-learn, imblearn
  Attempting uninstall: scikit-learn
    Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.23.2
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.23.2:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.23.2
Successfully installed imbalanced-learn-0.8.0 imblearn-0.0 scikit-learn-0.24.2
```

I also tried to install scikit-learn=0.23.2 via pip and I didn't get the warning in my local machine while loading the model. But scikit-learn should not installed via pip in the deployment environment. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

Whatever is in the `pip:` section of a Conda environment YAML gets installed *after* the Conda environment is created, and is run with the `pip install -U` command. The `-U` gives Pip the permission to upgrade any existing packages if it is necessary to install the specified packages. In this particular case, the version of `imblearn` must be incompatible with the `scikit-learn` version you have selected.

### Remove `imblearn`

Technically, you should be using `imbalanced-learn` not `imblearn`, as [stated in the package description](https://pypi.org/project/imblearn/0.0/). That also means you don't even need to install from PyPI, since `imbalanced-learn` is available through Conda Forge.

If you require having `scikit-learn=0.23` then you must use `imbalanced-learn=0.7`. This should be under the regular dependencies, not in the `pip:` section.

Comment: Thank you. Your Explanation is very informative. However, when I'm trying to install imbalanced-learn=0.7 or imbalanced-learn=0.7.0 under regular dependencies, I get ResolvePackageNotFound:  imbalancedlearn=0.7 . Do you know why this happens?

Comment: It's on the **conda-forge** channel. Either try it as `conda-forge::imbalanced-learn=0.7` or add `conda-forge` to the channels section.